# Converting XML to JSON and within the JSON object I am getting the character "↵" instead of the text for links

Tags: javascript, xml, json, parsing, converters

I'm using the x2js library to convert XML to JSON. It essentially instantly gives an entire JSON object to work with. However, some of the XML text contained links. As a result, in the JSON, the character "↵" shows up instead of the link text. When I go into my JavaScript file and try to parse through each character to see if it is equal to "↵", it's just a blank character, so I can't ever replace it.

The JSON looks like this when I output the entire object to the console:

```
div: Array[20]
  0: Object
    p: Array[2]
      0: Object
        title: "text is here, this text is OK, I have no problems"
      1: Object
        text: "Here is some blah blah, ↵ "
  1: Object
  ...
  ...
  19: Object
```

So within the console, I can see the arrow, which is supposed to be link text. I've tried printing the specific text text from JavaScript to the console, but the "↵" already has disappeared by then, just converted to space.

Is there a way to see immediately if the text contains a "↵"? Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON almost certainly does not actually contain the `↵` character. Rather, the JavaScript engine or logging library displaying the result to the console is representing a *newline* character (`\n`) with that special character to maintain formatting while still indicating a newline.

Therefore, if you want to check if a string contains that character, you'll have to check against `"\n"` instead. Likewise, you'll have to replace newlines if you want to remove them.